# fluid portrait images with max height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm having some issues with fluid images when using a max height. I'm trying to bound the image in a box that is at most 450x450 or any arbitrary box thats not in the same aspect ratio as the image. What's happening is that the width of the image is being restricted to 450px but the height is not and the image is overflowing the wrapper div.

my code is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iw4yOa0.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/5fuZ5/ for full code and css.

I know I could achieve this by using jquery but I need a responsive solution that doesn't require javascript.

Comment: Your image is broken so i tried it with a new image. It is scaling fine without any problems, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome v25.0.1364.97 m on windows and the image works for me. can you please fork a jsfiddle of it working with your image.

Comment: sure, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5fuZ5/1/

Comment: @Kev you used a landscape image. My question is about portrait images

Answer (score 0):

OK i've got a similar issue and could find nothing to help.  My situation is that i have a single column of images that are fluid (fit their container 100% in width) works fine for landscape images but portrait are huge as its the width being fitted, therefore tall and skinny image (portrait) is having its width fit to container thus making it massively tall.

My solution was to think about the container, if in the instance of a portrait image i set the container to be 50% of the landscape container then when i fit the images width (when portrait) to a smaller container i get them proportional (ish).

So wat you want is 2 containers to use, one for portrait and landscape, the landscape one will be the maximum width you want so 450px.  Now make your portrait container half a width so 225px (half of the width) if all your images are the same aspect ratio then they should all match nicely and give you a structured grid - or if single column the portrait images will be more or less as tall as the landscape images are wide.

If you want to see this working (for a short time) I'll leave this link up so you can see how i solved it.  The example is an email (please don't moan about poor coding, its not finished) template I'm making, where i have a single column of images (its responsive) both portrait and landscape - use a class on the table that contains the portrait image (class=portrait) but this could easily be a div.

http://www.sink140.com/sf-test/single.html

My main point is to stop thinking about trying to control the height, just control the container, let the image fill it, and by adjusting the width of the container (making it smaller) you naturally reduce the height of the image.

Aspect ratio of the images in general will ensure you can predict the layout as you have a baseline of sorts - portrait images relate to the landscape ones.

Hope this helps or at least give you another idea.